# Agregue una línea de total personalizada a los totales de los pedidos del administrador de WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

He cambiado la forma de como se presentan los datos de los pedidos. En este caso al ser una pagina de presupuesto, se puede sumar los costos de envio al precio del producto y esta suma es el precio final.

Este codigo realiza esto, y esta comprobado su funcionamiento:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers_2');
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers_2(){
echo '<th>Price</th>';
echo '<th>Tax</th>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values_2', 10, 3);
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values_2($product, $item, $item_id = null) {
$order_id = get_the_ID();
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$value = wc_price( $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
if($item['type']=="line_item"){
echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $order->get_total_tax() . '</td>';
}
}
```

Depurando el codigo y mirando en el log veo este error critico:

CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_subtotal() on bool in functions.php:85

La linea 85  es la siguiente:

```
$value = wc_price( $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
```

No entiendo el error, ni como se puede corregir.

Las siguientes lineas contienen algo mas de informacion:

```
public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values_2()
#1 /*/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#2 /*/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#3 /*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wc-multivendor-marketplace/views/emails/store-new-order.php(258): do_action()
#4 /*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(345): include('/home/certifacy...')
#5 /*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(364): wc_get_template()
#6 /*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wc-multivendor-marketplace/includes/store-emails/class-wcfmmp-email-store-new-order.php(150): wc_get_template_html()
#7 /*/public_html/wp-conten en /home/certifacyl/public_html/wp-content/themes/benzer/functions.php en la línea 86
```

Comment: Hola Victor, prueba cambiando $order->get_subtotal() por $order->get_subtotal_to_display()  a ver si eso te funciona. Saludos.

Comment: Hola og.lopar711 . ME salta el siguiente error  CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_subtotal_to_display() on bool in /***/public_html/wp-content/themes/benzer/functions.php:85

Comment: $value = wc_price( $order->get_subtotal_to_display() + $order->get_shipping_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );